# I am getting different created date and modified date with the same code when tested on two different JAVA programs?

Tags: java

I implemented this same code on two different Java program on same system i.e Windows 10, but the output I got was not similar.

```
public DateParser(String path){
    Path p = Paths.get(path);
    BasicFileAttributes attr;

    try {
        attr = Files.readAttributes(p, BasicFileAttributes.class);
        System.out.println("creationTime:     " + attr.creationTime());
        System.out.println("lastAccessTime:   " + attr.lastAccessTime());
        System.out.println("lastModifiedTime: " + attr.lastModifiedTime());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

OUTPUT:
**1st program:**
creationTime:     2016-11-11T04:02:43.14781Z
lastAccessTime:   2016-11-11T04:04:28.683961Z
lastModifiedTime: 2016-11-11T04:04:28.683961Z

**2nd program:**
creationTime: 2016-12-08T11:10:13.263119Z
lastAccessTime: 2016-12-08T12:19:51.453563Z
lastModifiedTime: 2016-11-30T09:00:13.404582Z
```

Comment: I can see no difference. I wonder why that is. Could it be it's because there's no output to see in the question text? Are you even sure you're reading attributes of the same file? Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Both the Java programs might be reading different files and you might be using [relative](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001708.htm) paths. The Java programs might be running from different locations.

Also check the following:

- Is the path argument passed same as in both programs?
- Is the path argument absolute or relative?

Comment: No, both the programs are reading the same file and I'm using absolute path.